# Why JavaFX- method .getLayoutBounds().getWidth() returns 0?

Tags: javafx, layout, bounds, borderpane

I need to dynamically retrieve the **width** of the left part of my **JavaFX-BorderPane**.
Here is the code-snippet, but both methods I use always return 0 although left component is laid out at this point of time...

```
double leftWidth = ((VBox) this.getLeft()).getWidth();
```

same with:

```
double leftWidth = ((VBox) this.getLeft()).getLayoutBounds().getWidth();
```

How to do this properly?

Here a mcve:

```
public class BorderPaneExample extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setText("Left side of BorderPane");
    BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
    root.setLeft(btn);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 640, 480);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);

    primaryStage.show();

    // ... later on retrieve the width of the left side:
    System.out.println(root.getLeft().getLayoutBounds().getWidth());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}}
```

Comment: You should create a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), honestly.. I cant tell you anything from what you've provided.

Comment: Yes u are right, sorry. I added some mcve to the question now which demonstrates the behaviour ...

Comment: worksforme - win10, fx11 and fx8_152 (don't have a more recent fx8)

Comment: it works for me as well, win 10, jdk and fx -12.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are calling them before `stage.show()` has happened.

Bounds are not initialized until the window is shown. Move them to be calculated later, or try to wrap them into `Platform.runLater()` as a workaround.

Comment: yes, this is what I thought also, but my mcve demonstrates, that this happens even if called after stage.show() ...

Comment: hmm, works for me... try to wrap it into `Platform.runLater()` even after `show()` which maybe not instantaneous

Comment: I wrapped it like this `        Platform.runLater(
                new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(root.getLeft().getLayoutBounds().getWidth());
            }
        });` but still returns 0. I use latest version of Java 1.8 platform jdk1.8.0_231 and NetBeans 11.0 IDE, maybe this is the reason?

Comment: @kleopatra is right —  it should work w/o random waiting. Do you see a button while running your app?

Comment: yes, everything works fine, the Window appears properly and layouted as expected, but no matter what I do, always get "0" as output on the console ...